# KMDF DMA transfer slows down after a few restarts

Tags: windows, driver, dma, kmdf

**Story:**
*I am developing a KMDF driver for a custom PCI-E board, which has a PLX9056 chip connecting to the PCI-E.*

*The driver and it's test software works perfectly after booting the computer, but after restarting the software and driver a several times, the transfer speed slows down from 160Mb/s to around 110 MB/s step by step.*

*(I have to disable and re-enable the driver everytime I want to restart the software, firmware bug, not my job atm.)*

**My main question is, is there any memory or anything connected to the DMA that can get fragmented and therefore make the transfers slower?**

The driver uses Scatter/Gather DMA, hardware supported, only 32bit. This only occurs when transferring data **to** the device.

The issue seems to be the way the driver handles the data/buffers. The PLX provided DMA testing software always gets the 160MB/s rate every time, even when our driver already broke and manages only 110MB/s. Therefore, the problem must be in our driver.

Reinstalling the driver does not solve the problem, only a reboot does.

Worth to mention, the software allocates a rather huge buffer (1GB), from which it sends the data to the device through the driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue.

The fragmentation of the memory caused the driver to not be able to allocate large continous blocks of memory after the OS has been running for a while.

Fixed by using Large-Page Support which allowed me to allocated huge continous memory pages.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/large-page-support